# Execute javascript as if it was pasted line by line

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I'd like to execute a sequence of javascript code on a website which involves a lot of loading of new pages, still continuing the execution at every freshly loaded page. This is an excerpt:

```
document.location.href = "https://www.somehost.com"
document.getElementById("userfield").value = "<username>"
document.getElementById("passfield").value = "<password>"
document.getElementById("loginbtn").click();
document.evaluate(".//a[.='Messages']",document,null,XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.click();
document.evaluate(".//a[.='Inbox']",document,null,XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

If I paste this line by line into Firefox' console (starting at about:blank), everything works fine and I get to my Inbox. However, if I paste the whole sequence, or encapsulate it into a function, I only get past the first step of loading the page where it tells me that `getElementByID` returns `null`. I also tried to do the same with a new window:

```
var new_window = window.open("https://www.somehost.com","_blank");
new_window.document.getElementById("userfield").value = "<username>"
new_window.document.getElementById("passfield").value = "<password>"
new_window.document.getElementById("loginbtn").click();
new_window.document.evaluate(".//a[.='Messages']",new_window.document,null,XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.click();
new_window.document.evaluate(".//a[.='Inbox']",new_window.document,null,XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Still no luck.

How can I execute this sequence as if I just pasted every single line one by one?

Does it have to do something with the javascript execution being faster than the website's loading process?

Comment: If loginbtn is a submit button, you load a new page and any script thereafter needs to wait for the new page to load. If the script is not from the same site, you will get access denied due to cross origin security. If they all come from the same site, you need to use setTimeout to wait for the new page to load into an iFrame or window other than where the script runs

Comment: Loading a new page replaces the current page. Your JS is part of the current page. So the JS from the current page can't manipulate the new page. (Unless, as per the previous comment, the new page loads in a different frame or window.)

Comment: is the js in the header of your html? where do you include it and how? and is the host you are accessing is some other domain, or still inside your own domain?

Comment: Thanks to all of you. All sites belong to the same domain that I do not own. So do I need to set a timeout for every single event which loads a new page (all clicking events)? And which option would be better: Working with a new window similar to my second example or using an iFrame?